# pyside-uic/pyuic4: command not found

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4, pyside

I'm running Python 2.7 on OS X Snow Leopard. I installed Python using Macports. Then, I installed py27-pyqt4 and py27-pyside, and I can't get them to work.

Python doesn't give errors when I import, but I get the following errors in the terminal when I test either:

> pyside-uic : command not found
>
> pyuic4 : command not found

Answer (score 1):

You are still using the default Mac OS Python and not using the new installed one.

1. Check the python version: python must be 2.7.
2. find the new
   version (should be inside /usr/local/bin )
3. update your
   .bash_profile PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
4. Try again and try to
   import PyQt4